# How to trigger a service in Angular from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, service

I'm trying to do this.

I need to push data from NodeJS (backend) to Angular (frontend) without any explicit request from Angular to NodeJS.

I was thinking of making an API request to Angular from NodeJS and Angular would listen to the API request via a Service and fetch data accordingly.

I'm not sure whether this is the right approach or is it possible in the first place, could someone guide me in the right direction?

Edit:

I'm trying to implement this for multiple Social Media Integrations in a One Page MEAN App. On button clicks, users get redirected to respective Social media authentication pages, after successful authorization, I'm able to fetch the accessTokens in the backend. I'm confused about how to send the data to frontend without passing the accessTokens in URL parameters.

Is there any other approach to implement it in a MEAN app?

Comment: Have you looked at https://socket.io/ ? Really easy to get it set up and have messages 'pushed' from the server to the client.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `WebSocket`. https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/node-js-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial-2def3a841b61

Comment: Sure, that's call a websocket, you can [find more information here](https://socket.io/)

Comment: If you are unable to use web sockets due to restrictions or limitations you could simply set up an angular service which polls an api endpoint at any given interval and when it receives the data it can do whatever you need it to do

Comment: @MolikMiah could you share a code snippet on how to poll an api endpoint

Comment: @trichetriche apart from `polling` and `WebSocket`, is there any other way?

Comment: Check every N seconds, but very heavy, data-consuming, and overall a pain in the a** ... If you gave more information, maybe I could direct you better !

Comment: @trichetriche I have updated my query

Comment: Well if it's only about the token, you can juste bypass the issue by putting your front & back on the same server ? Also, passing tokens in the URL isn't that bad, most of the web applications do that

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [socket module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) for pushing data from Nodejs to angular.

The socket module provides `emit` and `on` methods with the help of this you can broadcast data or send in the request also generate your own event please check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) for more information

Comment: I was able to solve it by using `socket.io`, but I want to avoid that approach. I have updated my question, could you have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use tokens as like JWT  (passport JWT strategy) and pass it to the client and store it in a cookie / local storage.  you can use these tokens to protect api's and/or socket.io connects.  after that you do whatever communication you want.  the client needs to open the connection to the server (via pull or websockets) or you need to use some form of push service.  The reason is, that for many clients they are behind address translation and cannot be reached directly.

Comment: I created JWT using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). But when the callback is called, how do I pass the JWT?

Comment: You can use authorization headers  (bearer token)

Comment: this is an example:  https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e, there are many tutorials

Comment: and most probaly for social authentication service you would user oauth2 no?

Comment: Yes I'm using oAuth 2 for authentication in all Social Media Platforms, but the callbacks are from Social Media platforms, how can I add authorization headers in such cases?

Comment: I tried it once with passport-google-oauth2  and it worked, but i don't know where the  token is stored.  I think if you use the libraries i think this is automatic.  you can check your debugger, network traffic/requests.   i'm using jwt direct now without social auth.